# Connection to a S3 instance using a service-connector

Tags: swisscomdev

I'm trying to create a service-connector to my s3 instance like this:

`cf service-connector 13001 mybucketname.ds31s3.swisscom.com:443`

But I get the following error:

```
Server-Error 403: Check of security groups failed (no access)
```

I have created my service key according to this [documentation](https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/service-connector/).

Connecting to my MongoDB works perfectly using a service connector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a misconfiguration due to security changes. We fixed the issue, so connecting to s3 with the service-connector should now work.

Answer (score 3):

You can access Swisscom's S3 directly without the service connector.

The error message suggests that your current org and space do no have access to the S3. This is usually the case is there is no app-binding for that service in the current space. Please check whether you created your service key in the right org and space.